# Is an app's core data database deleted when an app is updated from a App Store?

Tags: ipad, core-data, ios6

I have an app on the App Store which is now onto its second version. The app uses Core Data to store information that I do not want to be lost when an upgrade of the app is installed.

My question is if the user has version 1.0 installed on their iPad and has data stored in their core database, does this database get deleted when the version 1.1 update is downloaded and installed?

Comment: No, not without you trying to delete it, or looking in a different place. Your data files in the app sandbox are simply left in place when the update happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends entirely on you. When you set up a Core Data stack, you can point your NSPersistentStoreCoordinator at a particular file anywhere in your app's writable folders that you want. Where you place that file determines whether it gets migrated during an app update.

A common choice is to stick your database file in the user's Documents directory, which will cause iOS to copy it along when installing an update to your application. Then, on launch, you're responsible for dealing with that database as you see fit (updating data in it, migrating your schema, etc.). Placing the file elsewhere - inside a temporary directory, for example - may cause it to be lost during an update.

See the [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW3) and [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can I clarify - my line NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.sqlite"]; says that the database is in the Documents directory, and therefore is will not be deleted during the update? I understand from further reading that this is only the case if the model has not changed. If the model has changed then the database will certainly be deleted, wherever it is. It that correct?

Comment: Not quite. Your database is in the Documents directory, and so will *not* be deleted through an app upgrade. If you change your model in the upgrade, your database is *still* not deleted - it is *your responsibility* to migrate the data in that database appropriately. See [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) for more details.

Comment: @Tim because of iOS storage guidelines, I had to add "Do not Backup attribute" to the database file stored in documents directory.So is there any danger like system will delete my database file after taking backup on icloud or is there any possibility that I can loose my database(database file)? If yes what should I do to avoid this?

Comment: @ViruMax If you mark a file as not needing backup, the system will not delete it out from under you; it will simply not copy the file to iCloud. The potential remains that you could lose the file due to user action (say, if the user deletes your app); however, in most cases, you shouldn't do anything special to handle these cases.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be deleted unless you uncommented apples code in your delegates persistent store method or wrote it yourself.  If you are not deleting users database and have not wrote migration code the app will crash (if you made changes to your model).  Lightweight migration is straightforward and easy to implement.  You pass in a dictionary for the options (see below).
What did you change in your data model?

```
 NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],     NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],     NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                  configuration:nil
                                                      URL:storeUrl
                                                      options:options
                                                      error:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

Comment: In the latest update (now available on the App Store) there is no change to the model so from what you are saying users will not have a problem? However I am working on the next version where I have simply added 1 new attribute to an existing entity. It is this that I need to manage - is that correct?

Comment: Right - if there are no changes to the model, your database will continue to work after the upgrade. Adding an attribute is a change that is legal under so-called "lightweight" migration, but you need to change a line or two of code to enable that feature. If you make a change that Xcode can't infer a mapping for - like making an optional attribute required without a default value - you'll need to do more custom data migration.

Comment: Richard, to answer the first part of your response: yes, if there are no changes to your model then no migration is needed.  Since you are now changing an attribute youll need to add the code I provided in my previous response.  Also, be sure to version your model & not change anything on your existing one - click on your model.xcdatamodeld from the file browser then from the toolbar choose "editor" > "add new version model" & base it off of your current model.  Now click on the xcdatamodeld & from attributes click on file inspector & set the model to your new version.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely unrelated to CoreData, but I think I should share.

I had an app that would download additional resources, save them to a subfolder in Documents and store their paths in a .plist file (also in /Documents).

Because I was storing the full path, and using it later, when the user updated the app the path would no longer be valid (there is a "random letters/numbers" part in the path to the app sandbox, ***and that part changes when you update the app***)

Comment: Good point! The upgrade process basically installs a new clean copy of the app, then copies all the relevant files (including those in the Documents folder) over to that new install. It then removes the old copy of the app. This changes the absolute path to these files, so you should (almost) always be working with paths relative to your application root.